# Удаление из бинарного дерева

Tags: c, бинарное-дерево, дерево

Есть код. Суть - работа с бинарными деревьями. Предполагаемый функционал - добавление в бин. дерево, удаление, распечатка. Все функции кроме удаления работают. Предположительно проблема в том что я заношу в деревья через 2 указателя, а удаляю через один. Но это не точно. Прошу помощи разобраться.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "bintree.h"

void paste_node(Tree ** tr, int x)
{
    Tree *tree_bin;
    if ((*tr) == NULL) {
        tree_bin = (Tree *) malloc(sizeof(Tree));
        tree_bin->item = x;
        tree_bin->lchild = tree_bin->rchild = NULL;
        *tr = tree_bin;
        return;
    }

    if (x < (*tr)->item) {
        paste_node(&((*tr)->lchild), x);
    } else {
        paste_node(&((*tr)->rchild), x);
    }
}

Tree * minimum(Tree *tr)
{
    if (tr->lchild == NULL) return tr;
    return minimum(tr->lchild);
}

Tree* delete_node(Tree* tr, int num)
{ 
    if (tr == NULL) return tr;

    if (num < tr->item)
        tr->lchild = delete_node(tr->lchild, num);
    else if (num > tr->item)
        tr->rchild = delete_node(tr->rchild, num);
    else {
        if (tr->lchild == NULL) {
            Tree *tree_bin = tr->rchild;
            free(tr);
            return tree_bin;
        }
        else if (tr->rchild == NULL) {
            Tree *tree_bin = tr->lchild;
            free(tr);
            return tree_bin;
        }

        Tree *tree_bin = minimum(tr->rchild);
        tr->item = tree_bin->item;
        tr->rchild = delete_node(tr->rchild, tree_bin->item);
    }

    return tr;
}

void print_tree(Tree *tr, int depth)
{
    if (tr != NULL) {
        print_tree(tr->lchild, depth + 1);
        for(int i = 0; i < depth; ++i) printf("   ");
        printf("%d<\n", tr->item);
        print_tree(tr->rchild, depth + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: В методе для удаления вершины обязательно надо что-нибудь возвращать?

Comment: нет, не обязательно

Answer (score 3):

Алгоритм удаления из двоичного дерева существует давно, найти его можно в любой книге по структурам данных. Первые его шаги у Вас были реализованы вполне сносно, в частности Вы останавливали поиск по дереву, если текущая вершина была пустой, и продолжали его в случае, если ключ текущей вершины не был равен удаляемому. Далее следовали чуть более сложные шаги и скорее всего именно в них Вы и запутались. Собственно далее рассматривалось само удаление найденного узла и необходимо было рассмотреть 3 основных ситуации: у удаляемого узла нет детей (лист), у удаляемого узла есть хотя бы один потомок и у удаляемого узла есть оба потомка.

Первый случай довольно прост - если удаляется лист, то необходимо просто освободить память, выделенную для него и сообщить его родителю, что теперь он утратил одного потомка. Если у удаляемой вершины есть хотя бы один потомок, то необходимо перенести все данные (ключ, значение и ссылки на детей) из единственного потомка в удаляемую вершину, а затем освободить память, выделенную для того самого единственного потомка.

Третий случай - самый сложный. В случае, если у удаляемой вершины есть сразу два потомка, то тогда необходимо найти наименьший элемент в его правом поддереве и перенести его ключ и значение в удаляемый узел. Это вполне обоснованный шаг, ведь для заданных вершин можно построить не одно дерево, поэтому мы можем поменять корень подобным образом. Тем более найденный в правом поддереве элемент будет удовлетворять всем условиям - его ключ будет находиться между значениями ключей детей удаляемой вершины.

Однако у правого потомка удаляемого узла может совсем не быть левых поддеревьев. В таком случае поиск минимального ключа в правом поддереве бесполезен (все ключи всё-равно будут больше) и поэтому можно сразу перенести ключ и значение из правого потомка в удаляемый узел, поменяв при этом ссылку на правого потомка.

В итоге я немного переписал вашу функцию удаления:

```
void delete_node(Tree** tr, int num, Tree* parent)
{
    if (!(*tr)) return;

    if (num < (*tr)->item)
        delete_node(&((*tr)->lchild), num, *tr);
    else if (num > (*tr)->item)
        delete_node(&((*tr)->rchild), num, *tr);
    else {

        if (!(*tr)->lchild && !(*tr)->rchild) {//Если детей у удаляемого узла нет, то перед нами самый простой случай - листовой узел.

            if (parent) {//Родителю данного узла надо сообщить о том, что потомка у него теперь нет 

                if (parent->lchild) {

                    if (parent->lchild->item == (*tr)->item) { //Если удаляется левый потомок

                        parent->lchild = NULL;
                    }
                }
                if (parent->rchild) {

                    if (parent->rchild->item == (*tr)->item) { //Если удаляется правый потомок

                        parent->rchild = NULL;
                    }
                }
            }
            free(*tr); // Теперь можно освободить память
            *tr = NULL;
        } else if (!(*tr)->lchild || !(*tr)->rchild) { // Если у удаляемой вершины есть хотя бы один потомок

            Tree* nodeToRemove = NULL;
            if ((*tr)->lchild) { //Находим того самого единственного потомка удаляемой вершины

                nodeToRemove = (*tr)->lchild;
            } else {

                nodeToRemove = (*tr)->rchild;
            }
            //Скопировать все данные из единственного потомка удаляемой вершины
            (*tr)->lchild = nodeToRemove->lchild;
            (*tr)->rchild = nodeToRemove->rchild;
            (*tr)->item = nodeToRemove->item;
            //Освободить память, выделенную ранее для данного потомка
            free(nodeToRemove);
        } else { //Если у удаляемой вершины есть оба потомка, то согласно алгоритму необходимо найти наименьший элемент в правом поддереве удаляемого элемента

            if (!(*tr)->rchild->lchild) { //Если у правого поддерева нет левых потомков, то это означает, что у всех потомков значение ключа больше, а значит надо просто скопировать значения из правого потомка в удаляемый элемент

                (*tr)->item = (*tr)->rchild->item; // Скопировать значение из правого потомка
                Tree* rightRIghtChild = (*tr)->rchild->rchild;
                free((*tr)->rchild); // Освбодить память, выделенную для правого потомка
                (*tr)->rchild = rightRIghtChild;
            } else {

                Tree* minNodeParent = minimum((*tr)->rchild); //Поиск наименьшего элемента в правом поддереве (он обязательно найдётся, случай когда его нет был разобран выше)
                (*tr)->item = minNodeParent->lchild->item; //Скопировать значение из наименьшего жлемента в правом поддереве в удаляемый элемент
                free(minNodeParent->lchild);
                minNodeParent->lchild = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ешё пришлось немного переписать функцию поиска минимального элемента (чтобы была возможность получить сразу родителя вершины с наименьшим ключом):

```
Tree * minimum(Tree *tr)
{
    if (!tr->lchild->lchild) return tr;
    return minimum(tr->lchild);
}
```

Вызывать полученную функцию можно так:

```
delete_node(&t, 11, NULL);
```

Comment: И что произойдет, если нужно удалять корень дерева? Видимо, как минимум, подобная функция должна возвращать новый (или старый, если удаляли не корень) указатель на корень. Вообще, imho все можно сделать проще, если сравнивать `num` не с `item` в текущем узле а с `item` в его левом и правом потомках.

Comment: @avp Из корня данной функцией теперь тоже удалять можно. Ни в коем случае не говорю, что данный вариант является самым лучшим, но возможно он хоть немного поможет автору найти правильное решение (либо мотивирует остальных участников предоставить более элегантный вариант ответа).

Comment: Ok. Наверное это поможет ТС. Я не вчитывался в код, может и другие особо не будут, так что возможно (для улучшения ответа) будет полезно изложить основные идеи алгоритма словами в ответе перед кодом. Например, явно сказать, какой узел (левое или правое поддерево) станет новым корнем при удалении существующего  корня. (поскольку есть функция `minimum`, похоже правый потомок корня станет новым корнем)

Comment: @avp Я отредактировал ответ, добавил описание алгоритма.

Comment: Отлично, я думаю остальные участники также оценят. Теперь осталось ждать реакции ТС -)